# Modify dynamic element after script completes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm relatively new to JavaScript, so please bear with me.

I run an instance of the Blackboard Learn LMS. Feel sorry for me later. Blackboard displays different modules to end users to show different pieces of information. The **Announcements** module contains **non-editable code** that sends an Ajax request to display all system-wide and course-specific announcements for that particular user:

```
<div id="Announcements">
    <div id="div_1_1"> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function () {
            new Ajax.Request('/webapps/portal/execute/tabs/tabAction', {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: 'action=refreshAjaxModule&modId=_1_1&tabId=_2830_1&tab_tab_group_id=_155_1',
                onSuccess: function (transport) {
                    try {
                        var res = transport.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('contents')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                        $('div_1_1').innerHTML = res.stripScripts();
                        page.globalEvalScripts(res, true);
                    } catch (e) {
                        $('div_1_1')
                            .innerHTML = 'Module information is temporarily unavailable. Please reload the page. <!--' + e.toString()
                            .escapeHTML()
                            .gsub('-', '&#045;') + '-->';
                    }
                },
                onFailure: function (transport) {
                    $('div_1_1').innerHTML = 'Error loading module.';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

The module brings up a lot of redundant information that I'd like to hide. Since there's no way to edit that particular code, I've been trying to figure out a way to do one of the following:

1. Modify the module's contents with additional scripting from another source on the page.
2. Copy the module's contents to a new, editable module, and display that one instead,

Both methods have proven impossible because the script in the **Announcements** module only runs once the page has loaded entirely, so there's no way to run a script afterward or wait until the process has completed.

Any ideas on how I might be able to modify the contents without editing its code directly?

Comment: Presuming that there's a container element (i.e. div) around the module's contents, you might be able to hook a DOMSubtreeModified event on that container with a test to see if it's loaded (checking for a particular child element that's only there when it's done loading).  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified
Then destroy the event listener and modify as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the DOMSubtreeModified event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();p
    $j("#div_1_1").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
        var div = document.getElementById("div_1_1");
        var inner = div.innerHTML;
        inner = inner.substring(
            inner.indexOf("<!-- Display course/org announcements -->")
        );
        div.innerHTML = inner;
    });
</script>
```